SocketException : Broken Pipe in RabbitMQ
I have a cluster with three RabbitMQ nodes.
Everything works fine until my connection to the cluster is closed when an error appears:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer

Followed by :
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

My logs in rabbit are :
[warning] <0.1469.0> closing AMQP connection <0.1469.0> (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:51068 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5672 - connectionFactory#38929da:0, vhost: '/', user: 'awake', duration: '9M, 41s'):
[warning] <0.1469.0> client unexpectedly closed TCP connection

After that, I have to run docker compose down/up to reconnect my application to the cluster (when it is too slow to recover a connection by itself). Then my service restarts to consume messages, but sometimes the connection is closed again with the same errors.
It seems to appear when a lot of messages are consumed by the cluster (~1000/s)
I set the heartbeats to 3600 (on client and server side which is high for my tests) and my connectionTimeout on client side is 1500000 (25 min) :
connectionFactory.setConnectionTimeout(1500000);
connectionFactory.setRequestedHeartBeat(3600);


Any idea why my connection is closed in less than 10 min ? Thank you

See if this helps somehow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37110976/rabbitmq-connection-reset-by-peer
