# RabbitMQ Errors AlreadyClosedException

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, servicestack

I have a .Net 6 microservice application which is receiving occasional RabbitMQ errors although there doesn't appear to be an excessive rate of messages on the queue it is trying to write to.

The error returned looks like

> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.AlreadyClosedException: Already closed: The
> AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by
> Library, code=541, text='Unexpected Exception', classId=0, methodId=0,
> cause=System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
> connection: Connection reset by peer.\n --->
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (104): Connection reset by peer\n
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
> Int32 count)\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\n   at
> RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.InboundFrame.ReadFrom(NetworkBinaryReader
> reader)\n   at
> RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.MainLoopIteration()\n   at
> RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.MainLoop()\n   at
> RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.EnsureIsOpen()\n   at
> RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.CreateModel()\n
> at ServiceStack.RabbitMq.RabbitMqExtensions.OpenChannel(IConnection
> connection) in
> /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack.RabbitMq/RabbitMqExtensions.cs:line
> 18\n   at ServiceStack.RabbitMq.RabbitMqProducer.get_Channel() in
> /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack.RabbitMq/RabbitMqProducer.cs:line
> 47\n   at ServiceStack.RabbitMq.RabbitMqProducer.Publish(String
> queueName, IMessage message, String exchange) in
> /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack.RabbitMq/RabbitMqProducer.cs:line
> 99\n   at
> ASM.Helios.ServiceHosting.RabbitMqServiceRequestLogger.Log(IRequest
> request, Object requestDto, Object response, TimeSpan
> requestDuration)\n   at
> ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.LogRequest(IRequest req, Object
> requestDto, Object response) in
> /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/Host/ServiceRunner.cs:line
> 233

We have found that increasing the number of service instances does seem to help reduce the frequency of the errors, but they will still occur.

I was wondering if it is a similar issue to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438843/rabbitmq-error-timeout/36114095#36114095) stackoverflow question, in which case maybe setting the prefetch count to a lower value would help.

The code for setting up our rabbitMQ connection using the serviceStack implementation of rabbit looks like:

```
   private static void SetUpRabbitMqConnection(IServiceDiscovery serviceDiscovery)
        {
            MessageService = RabbitMqServerFactory.GetRabbitMqServer(serviceDiscovery).Result;
            MessageService.ConnectionFactory.SocketReadTimeout = 1000;
            MessageService.ConnectionFactory.SocketWriteTimeout = 1000;
            MessageService.ConnectionFactory.RequestedHeartbeat = 3;
            MessageService.RetryCount = 0;

            MqClient = (RabbitMqQueueClient)MessageService.MessageFactory.CreateMessageQueueClient();

            ResponseQueueName = MqClient.GetTempQueueName(); //This creates a temp queue which gets auto deleted when nothing is connected to it

            RabbitMqConsumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(MqClient.Channel);
            MqClient.Channel.BasicConsume(queue: ResponseQueueName, consumer: RabbitMqConsumer, noLocal: true);
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Awaiting RPC requests");

            RabbitMqConsumer.Received -= RabbitMqConsumerOnReceived;
            RabbitMqConsumer.Received += RabbitMqConsumerOnReceived;

            Disconnected = false;
        }
```

Would adding a line like:  `MqClient.Channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize, prefetchCount,global);` help?
What are sensible values for the 3 parameters? I think the defaults are 0, 20, and false.
Or is there a different configuration change that might help?